# where do we get the props in render method in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mern

i have passed a component to child element , one thing i am confused about is render methods get **props** as parameters  and then we pass them as props to other **element**. where and how are we getting these props inside parameters  of render method . check the code and specifically the render method and props used in it thanks

here is the code:

```
return (
    <div>
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) =>
          localStorage.getItem("authToken") ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect to="/" />
          )
        }
      />
    </div>
```

here is code from parent element

```
 <Privateroute exact path="/signup"   component={Register} />
```

Comment: I am not sure about your question

Comment: @moshfiqrony hi , thanks for your time ,   in the render method u can see props and then these props are passed to <Component   { ...props}/>. my question i s where are we gettting these props from ? if you have time i can share the youtube tutorial link and you can get more clear idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to think abou the props at first you have to understand parameters in functions.

In function you can call a function with parameters. The parameters are optional if you pass it will pass the value, if you don't pass it will be null. Sometime if you use default value for a parameter in function definition it will hold that value.

Let's come to props now. props are same as parameters. But in this case. React does this for you and it is dynamic. Whatever props you will pass with the component and react by default will pass some extra props.

So the props are automatically generated by react if you use any global component. Like `history`, `location`, and etc are passed or created if you use `react-router-dom` browser router.

Finally. In one words props are same as parameters and react also create dome dynamically.

Comment: right  so what values/properties does props have here render={props => (
            localStorage.getItem("authToken") ?
                <Component {...props} />

Comment: That props are some of the props that is coming from the ```Route``` components. The Route components does all the work for the extra props and pass it.

Comment: And the props that it automatically adds is ```history```, ```location``` and some other call backs

Comment: The extra props are generated from the root window object and helps us to redirect, parse query string, and etc

Comment: so props here render={props => (  localStorage.getItem("authToken") ? <Component {...props} /> contain nothing more but things like history , location etc and they are automatically generated by react  right?

Comment: Almost right. They are automatically generated by the package from which you imported the Route component.

Comment: right thanks a lot for your help,  your answers really helped me understand the concept  thanks  again  :),

Answer (score 1):

**Here's the working example:**

**Privateroute.js component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Privateroute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            localStorage.getItem("authToken") ?
                <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to="/signup" />
        )} />
    );
};

export default Privateroute;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Privateroute from './components/PrivateRoute';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Privateroute component={Register} path="/signup" exact />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: bro i  am only confused in one part {props => (
            localStorage.getItem("authToken") ?
                <Component {...props} />   where does props come from bcz in pareant we have not passed any other except a component

Comment: When you create a component, you can pass props in it's parameter as `const Home = (props) => ( <div>Hello</div> )`. In the same way, instead of having a new React element created for you using the component prop, you can pass in a function to be called when the location matches. The render prop function has access to all the same route props (match, location and history) as the component render prop.

Comment: thanks a lot ,  now i understand this render method more clearly , thanks again for your time :)